# Running setup.py install for regex ... error is driving me crazy

Tags: python, regex, anaconda

I am begging for help! I cannot get anything to work in anaconda anymore and I am trying to resolve it since days. I get the following error when I try to install several packages:

```
Building wheel for regex (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wc/1pgwt_g16sn0026xr90vh_x80000gn/T/pip-install-6dc2clpx/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wc/1pgwt_g16sn0026xr90vh_x80000gn/T/pip-install-6dc2clpx/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/wc/1pgwt_g16sn0026xr90vh_x80000gn/T/pip-wheel-r01lufl5
       cwd: /private/var/folders/wc/1pgwt_g16sn0026xr90vh_x80000gn/T/pip-install-6dc2clpx/regex/
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex
  copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex
  copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex
  copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex
  copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex
  running build_ext
  building 'regex._regex' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex_3
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex
```

I tried everything. I uninstalled anaconda, I tried `pip install regex` NOTHING works. I am desperate. I cannot work since days. Please help me.

Comment: Looks like you're missing xcode. "missing xcrun at:"

Comment: Python has a built-in regex library called `re`

Comment: It's true I have no xcode installed at the moment. But I never did. Everything worked fine for me, until I tried to install a google-colab package, which caused an error. Afterwards, some modules were automatically uninstalled or downgraded and since then I run into problem after problem.. aht can i do with the ´re´library?

Comment: Please I need help, I will lose my job if I can't start working again soon

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did u get solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure regex version is up to date in requirements.txt. For me it works when I set regex==2022.3.2.